# Atribuir números à frases em PHP

Tags: php, random

Olá, tenho um certo número de frases, e preciso que toda vez que o usuário enviasse um certo form, aparecesse uma dessas frases, utilizando uma função aleatória, mas não sei nem como iniciar, não tenho nenhum código até o momento.

Comment: Essas frases estão onde?

Comment: E vão aparecer onde?

Comment: @rray elas serão  previamente escritas, se for o caso, receberão o valor de uma variável

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira aparecerão assim que o usuário logar em sua conta.

Comment: Estão em um arquivo? no banco? é uma por usuário?

Comment: @rray elas ainda não tem um local especifico, aonde ficaria mais fácil de usá-las?

Comment: Elas vão aparecer quando o usuário envia o form (na tela de login, presumo), ou na tela seguinte, depois de logado? Já deu pra perceber que a sua pergunta está bem abrangente, né?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenta desta forma

```
$array = array(
    'Frase 1',
    'Frase 2',
    'Frase 3'
);

$aleatorio = rand(0, count($array) -1);

echo $array[$aleatorio];
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho, obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Pelo que você especificou na sua pergunta posso dar uma ideia de como fazer isto de forma simples,
   utilize um array para guardar suas frases e mande a função array_rand() retonar um indice 
   aleatorio que sera a frase escolhida.

```
$frases = array('frase 1','frase 2','frase 3','frase 4');

echo $frases[array_rand($frases)];
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/rQCqwl)